# print dictionary of dictionaries as table

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

Simplifying my problem, I have a dictionary of dictionaries in my pipeline that I want to print as table.

For example. This is my dictionary printed using this:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
        if len(v) >= float(2):
                print k , v

NODE_2908 [{'NODE_2908_1': 'gi|497712399|'}, {'NODE_2908_2': 'gi|817665741|'}]
NODE_334 [{'NODE_334_2': 'gi|639993929|'}, {'NODE_334_3': 'gi|652409655|'}]
NODE_246 [{'NODE_246_1': 'gi|754171522|'}, {'NODE_246_2': 'gi|658510970|'}]
```

A simple text file with their values.
But, what I want is to print "v" as tabular avoiding special characters "(,', [, ),{" and separated by "\t".
Like this:

```
NODE_2908   NODE_2908_1: gi|497712399   NODE_2908_2: gi|817665741|
NODE_334    NODE_334_2: gi|639993929|   NODE_334_3: gi|652409655|
NODE_246    NODE_246_1: gi|754171522|   NODE_246_2: gi|658510970|
```

I tried this with any success:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
        if len(v) >= float(2):
                print k + '\t' + str(('\t').join(sorted(v)))
```

Pop-up a error:

```
print k + '\t' + str(('\t').join(sorted(v)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, dict found
```

Suggestions conserving this structure will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's this: `if len(v) >= float(2)` all about?

Comment: I included this to print only the keys with more than 2 values.

Comment: Yes, clearly, but why use `float`?

Comment: Because using directly "2" it doesn't work.

Comment: ??? `2` certainly works.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you and now my code have a few less letters. (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of messy, but it should work:

```
from itertools import chain
for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) >= 2:
        print("\t".join(chain([k], *(item for dd in v for item in dd.items()))))
```

Result:

```
NODE_2908   NODE_2908_1 gi|497712399|   NODE_2908_2 gi|817665741|
NODE_246    NODE_246_1  gi|754171522|   NODE_246_2  gi|658510970|
NODE_334    NODE_334_2  gi|639993929|   NODE_334_3  gi|652409655|
```

Or, perhaps without itertools:

```
In [25]: for k, v in d.items():
    ...:     if len(v) >= 2:
    ...:         print(k + '\t' + "\t".join(s for dd in v for t in dd.items() for s in t))
    ...:         
    ...:         
NODE_2908   NODE_2908_1 gi|497712399|   NODE_2908_2 gi|817665741|
NODE_246    NODE_246_1  gi|754171522|   NODE_246_2  gi|658510970|
NODE_334    NODE_334_2  gi|639993929|   NODE_334_3  gi|652409655|
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do something better converting "v" to string and after replace.

```
for k, v in dict_blast.items():
        if len(v) >= float(2):
                print k + '\t' + str(v).replace("[{'", "").replace("': '", ": ").replace("'}, {'" , "\t").replace("'}]", "")
```

I know that it is not clear and beautiful.